# Aligning icon and div using bootstrap classes only

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this code

```
<div class="row">
        <h3><b>We've got you covered</b></h3>
        <h6>Find things to do in cities around the world</h6>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="div-icon col">
        <i class="fas fa-info h1"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="div-content col">
        <b>Explore top attractions</b>
        <p><small>Experience the best of your destination with attractions, tours, activities, and more</small></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        </div>
```

I want the icon and text to align like this

[image]

The icon and text code

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="div-icon col">
        <i class="fas fa-info h1"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="div-content col">
        <b>Explore top attractions</b>
        <p><small>Experience the best of your destination with attractions, tours, activities, and more</small></p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Using `col` and `col` does not divide the `col-md-4` into two. Is there a way i can display icon and content side by side using only bootstrap classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### you have to wrap your inner cols with `div class="row"` and give `cols` specific size

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="div-icon col-md-1">
        <i class="fas fa-info h1"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="div-content col-md-11">
        <b>Explore top attractions</b>
        <p><small>Experience the best of your destination with attractions, tours, activities, and more</small></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```